# BeanPostProcessor и SpringMVC @Controller проблема с маппингом

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, proxy, controller

Над методами `Spring MVC @Controller` стоит `custom` аннотация, которая передаёт параметры метода и его названия в свой сервис, для работы аннотации данный контроллер "оборачивается" в прокси в `CustomBeanPostProcessor`. Соответственно, при запуске приложения создаётся прокси нашего контроллера, но при этом теряются все `@RequestMapping` над методами, и получается, что при запросе с клиента запрос не обрабатывается, поскольку бинпостпроцессор работает только в своём контексте `ApplicationContext`, а бин РестКонтроллера в `WebApplicationContext`. Вопрос, как прописать зависимость в `WebApplicationContext`, чтоб контроллер не "терял" маппинг?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. Как вариант, для контроллеров можно сделать интерсептор (`HandlerInterceptorAdapter`).

Например, в методе

```
preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any?): Boolean
```

где, если `handler` - это экземпляр `HandlerMethod`, то до кастомной аннотации можно добраться через через `getMethod()` и далее выполнить кастомную логику.

Тоже самое можно сделать в кастомном фильтре, см., например, [здесь](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/67240da308f17720e7cf127321ff7ed39c7a6b1e/micrometer-spring-legacy/src/main/java/io/micrometer/spring/web/servlet/MetricsFilter.java).