# Spring @Controller + BeanPostProcessor with proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, логирование, аннотации

Похожие вопросы, но ответов на них так и не последовало, возможно сейчас сюда забредет гуру спринга и разложит все по полочкам:
[тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744905/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-proxy-%D0%B8%D0%B7-beanpostprocessor) и [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515253/beanpostprocessor-%D0%B8-springmvc-controller-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Суть проблемы: пишу свой BeanPostProcessor (BPP) для "логгирования" классов, которые помечены моей аннотацией. Соответственно, если класс помечен данной аннотацией, то пускаем его через прокси и пишем логику необходимую. Однако, если класс был помечен другими аннотациями (например @Controller), то Proxy это все дело игнорирует и на выходе мы получаем логгирующийся класс, но без всех остальных наворотов.

Вопрос: Каким способом можно реализовать BPP и проксировать в нем классы так, чтобы другая логика, связанная с аннотациями не терялась? Или же можно обойтись как нибудь без прокси (но с BPP). (Аспекты не предлагать, вопрос именно в BPP).

**UPD:** Как один из вариантов решения данной проблемы - объявлять бины не с помощью аннотаций. Но это ограничения, которые нежелательны. Так же будут "заигнорены" другие аннотации, кроме "пользовательской, по которой создается прокси.

Comment: попробуйте аспект, вместо BeanPostProcessor

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо за совет, но в вопросе просил без предложения аспектов. Как решить с аспектам - известное дело, авот с BPP - интересное :)

Comment: так вам это интересно чисто с академической точки зрения?

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev, да, это было полезно для понимания того, как это все происходит внутри. Несомненно, аспекты являлись бы решением проблемы, но не данного вопроса.

Comment: возможно дело в том, что у стандартного прокси объекта теряются аннотации, если они объявлены у имплементации, а не интерфейса. по идее проблема должна решиться, если использовать для создания прокси cglib

Comment: @DmitryTerentjev, Посмотрел на cjlib, почитал. Да, возможно это то, что нужно, но руки пока еще не дошли. Постараюсь после нового года отписаться по этому поводу, что и как, сработало или нет. Спасибо! Возможно стоит оформить комментарий, как ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Надеюсь мой ответ не слишком поздно для тебя

У меня есть подозрение, что ты не правильно создаешь прокси

У меня была похожая задача, мне было необходимо логировать реквест и респонс контроллеров, если на методе была повешена моя аннотация @Logging

Реализация моей задачи выглядит следующим образом. Аннотация с двумя параметрами, для гибкой настройки логирования реквеста и респонса (мне не всегда необходимо логировать респонс):

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Logging {
    boolean isRequest() default true;
    boolean isResponse() default true;
}
```

БинПостПроцессор выглядит следующим образом. Для создания динамическим прокси на лету, я использовал CGLIB, т.к. она работает быстрее стандартных инструментов JDK:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoggingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private Map<String, Class> loggingBeans = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class<?> beanClass = bean.getClass();
        if (Arrays.stream(beanClass.getMethods()).anyMatch(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Logging.class))) {
            loggingBeans.put(beanName, beanClass);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Class originalBean = loggingBeans.get(beanName);
        if (originalBean != null) {
            Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
            enhancer.setSuperclass(originalBean);
            enhancer.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, proxy) -> {
                Optional<Method> originalMethod = Arrays.stream(originalBean.getMethods())
                        .filter(method::equals)
                        .findFirst();

                if (originalMethod.isPresent()) {
                    Logging annotation = originalMethod.get().getAnnotation(Logging.class);
                    if (annotation != null) {
                        if (annotation.isRequest()) {
                            log.info("{}#{}: {}", originalBean.getSimpleName(), method.getName(), Arrays.asList(args).toString());
                        }
                        Object invoke = proxy.invoke(bean, args);
                        if (annotation.isRequest()) {
                            log.info("{}#{}: {}", originalBean.getSimpleName(), method.getName(), invoke != null ? invoke.toString() : "void");
                        }
                        return invoke;
                    }
                }
                return method.invoke(bean, args);
            });
            return enhancer.create();
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Кусок кода с использованием аннотации из контроллера:

```
@GetMapping("/type")
@Logging(isResponse = false)
public Object getTypes() {
    //мясо метода
}
```